# Рисуем на php

Tags: php

*Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане :)*

Вот возник такой у меня вопросик, как это рисуют на **php**? Почитал некие статьи в **Гугле**, но кроме как *ЗдАраВенных* и не понятных скриптов я ничего не нашел.

Может ли кто мне объяснить как такое прокрутить?

Заранее спасибо.

**Интересно:**

Мне, просто, покажите, пожалуйста, как, например, рисовать прямую или кривую.)

Comment: Как-то вы плохо искали. Смотрите [простейшие примеры](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dzv-s3g)

Comment: @Deonis, да скорее всего, что плохо искал, спасибо огромное.

Comment: @IamS, А вообще, конечно же рисование на php - это уже шаг отчаяния )) На будущее, покопайте какую-нибудь библиотеку: Paper.js, Processing.js, Raphael.js и рисовать будет гораздо приятней. Лично на мой вкус - это [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), но выбор за вами ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Как нарисовать линию (PHP)](http://expange.ru/e/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E_(PHP))

> Линия в PHP рисуется при помощи функции `bool imageline(resource image, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int color)`. Функция принимает 6 параметров: изображение-ресурс, 4 параметра с координатами линии и цвет.

Comment: Огонь, то, что искал :) Спасибо.

Comment: Но для этого сервер должен был быть собран с функцией поддержки библиотеки GD2

Answer (score 1):

Мб Вы про это: [GD and Image Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)?